# The form tag disappears after running Jquery

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, woocommerce

I'm new to jQuery.
I try to change the content of a div while user selects it.
This div is related to one of the payment gateways of wordpress/woocommerce.
I use this add_action to do that: `woocommerce_review_order_before_payment`
And I'm trying to display results of installment based on user inputs (period of each cheque, total sum, amount of each cheques and number of cheques).

This information is taken from a PHP file that is called up with the user data. (The file has been tested and is working fine.) This is the link for example:
`http://******/calc/calc.php?Amont=100000&Period=3&InstallmentCount=12`

Now when I select the "cheque option" and press the submit button, instead of sending data via Ajax, the whole page is sent to the server. After checking the codes, I found that when selecting this option, all the codes will be added to the desired div, but the form tag at the beginning of this code set, will not be added, this is result from "Chrome inspect":

```
<div class="payment_box payment_method_cheque" style="">
    <table align="center" style="width:40%;text-align:center;margin: 0 auto;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:center">
                    <input type="hidden" name="Amont" id="ch_amont" value="7350000">
                    <label>Period:</label><br>
                    <select name="Period" id="ch_period">
                        <option value="1">1 month</option>
                        <option value="2">2 months</option>
                        <option value="3">3 months</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:center"><br>
                    <label>Number of installment</label><br>
                    <select name="InstallmentCount" id="ch_inst">
                        <option value="6">6 months</option>
                        <option value="12">12 months</option>
                        <option value="18">18 months</option>
                        <option value="24">24 months</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:center"><br>
                    <input type="submit" class="button" name="submit_btn" id="submit_btn" value="Calculate my installment">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div id="server-results"><!-- For server results --></div><br>
</div>
```

As you see there is no form tag in it:
`<form id="my_form" method="POST" 
onsubmit="event.preventDefault();_cal_Function();">`
This line is omitted.

I tried to add this line manually via the "Chrome browser inspect", but it disappears after adding and there is no error in console.
This is the whole code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_payment', 'refresh_payment_methods' );

function refresh_payment_methods(){
    global $woocommerce, $product;
    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        (function($){
            $( 'form.checkout' ).on( 'change', 'input[name^="payment_method"]', function(event) {
                var payment_method = $('form.checkout').find('input[name^="payment_method"]:checked').val();
                if(payment_method == 'cheque'){
                    var theText = '<form id="my_form" method="post" onsubmit="event.preventDefault();_cal_Function();">';
                    theText += '<table align="center" style="width:40%;text-align:center;margin: 0 auto;"><tbody><tr><td style="text-align:center">';
                    theText += '<input type="hidden" name="Amont" id="ch_amont" value="<?php echo $woocommerce->cart->total; ?>">';
                    theText += '<label>Period:</label><br/>';
                    theText += '<select name="Period" id="ch_period"><option value="1">Every 1 month</option><option value="2">Every 2 months</option><option value="3">Every 3 months</option> </select>';
                    theText += '</td></tr><tr><td style="text-align:center">';
                    theText += '<br/><label>Number of installment</label><br/>';
                    theText += '<select name="InstallmentCount" id="ch_inst"><option value="6">Every 6 months</option><option value="12">Every 12 months</option><option value="18">Every 18 months</option><option value="24">Every 24 months</option></select>';
                    theText += '</td></tr><tr><td style="text-align:center">';
                    theText += '<br/><input type="submit" class="button" name="submit_btn" id="submit_btn" value="Calculate my installment" >';
                    theText += '</td></tr></tr></tbody></table>';
                    theText += '</form>';
                    theText += '<div id="server-results"><!-- For server results --></div><br/>';

                    $( "div.payment_method_cheque" ).html( theText );

                }else{
                    $('body').trigger('update_checkout');
                }
            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        function _cal_Function() {
            document.getElementById("server-results").innerHTML = "Calculating...";
            var _ch_amont  = document.getElementById('ch_amont');
            var _ch_period = document.getElementById('ch_period');
            var _ch_inst   = document.getElementById('ch_inst');

            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.open("GET", "http://*****/calc/calc.php?Amont="+_ch_amont.value+"&Period="+_ch_period.value+"&InstallmentCount="+_ch_inst.value);
            // Defining event listener for readystatechange event
            request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                // Check if the request is compete and was successful
                if(this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
                    // Inserting the response from server into an HTML element
                    document.getElementById("server-results").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                }
            };

            // Sending the request to the server
            request.send();
        }
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

After doing all the tests I found on the internet, I found a way but to ask the question here. Forgive me if my English is not good and thank you for guiding me.

Comment: With jQuery you are trying to add a form inside the checkout form, and this can't really work. Instead you should use Ajax. Also you doesn't need to use jQuery to display your fields inside a payment gateway tab. So you are not using the right way to make it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem and could solve it, so here is what I did:
`$( "div.payment_method_cheque" ).html( theText );`
This line was the problem, instead of html I tried replaceWith and it is working well.
Ofcourse I had to add this line top of theText:
`var theText = '<div class="payment_box payment_method_cheque" style="">';`
and this one at the end of block:
`theText += '</div>';`
Maybe jQuery has a better method for this, and I'd be happy to share if anyone knows.

Comment: Alternatively, you could look into AJAX to switch out elements. Load your `payment_method_cheque` specific stuff into a div through AJAX, then upon completion of the form, switch it with the `payment_box` specific stuff.

Comment: What is not very logic, is that you are adding a form into checkout form and this is not the right way… Instead you should use Ajax!